# How to remove the white bar above keyboard suggestion bar in Chrome Browser on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, html, google-chrome, web-applications

I been searching a way, with HTML5 or something like that, to remove the white bar on the keyboard that appears in the Chrome Browser for iOS.

When we want input a text in the URL or any textbox on Chrome appears a white bar obove the keyboard with two arrows and a DONE button as the following image:

[Capture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuri4.png)

And my questions are the following:

First, What is the name of that bar?

And finally, How can i remove the bar? if it is possible!

Comment: 'keyboard accessory bar' or 'form accessory bar' are names I have seen used for it

Comment: Thanks a lot mao.